# R POSIXlt attrib shows IST as +6:30 whereas IST is +5:30

Tags: r, posixlt

R output reads

POSIXlt in R shows

```
attr(,"tzone")
#[1] "" "IST""+0630"
```

whereas the actual IST (Indian Standard Time) is GMT +5:30

Why is the difference and where is it explained in R documentation

The entire command with output for your perusal (thanks in advance for the reply)

```
unclass(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))
$sec
[1] 36.357

$min
[1] 32

$hour
[1] 21

$mday
[1] 21

$mon
[1] 3

$year
[1] 120

$wday
[1] 2

$yday
[1] 111

$isdst
[1] 0

$zone
[1] "IST"

$gmtoff
[1] 19800

attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""      "IST"   "+0630"
```

Comment: This has probably to do with daylight savings time. In India, do the clocks go (1h00) forward in Summer?

Comment: @RuiBarradas No they don't. I guess OP needs to provide more context to debug this.

Comment: > unclass(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))
$sec
[1] 36.357

$min
[1] 32

$hour
[1] 21

$mday
[1] 21

$mon
[1] 3

$year
[1] 120

$wday
[1] 2

$yday
[1] 111

$isdst
[1] 0

$zone
[1] "IST"

$gmtoff
[1] 19800

attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""      "IST"   "+0630"

Comment: @Rui Barradas Thanks for the reply but India doesnt have any DST

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for the reply, please find the question edited

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a mix of

- India's timezone not being an integer offset from GMT but an integer plus half an hour;
- IEEE-754 rounding defined as [rounding half (0.5) to the nearest even number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

You can see in the question's output the list member `$gmtoff`:

```
unclass(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))$gmtoff
[1] 19800
```

And this is 5.5 hours from GMT:

```
19800/3600
#[1] 5.5
```

Now round it:

```
round(19800/3600)
#[1] 6
```